# $f$ and $g$ be nilpotent endomorphism such that : $\ker (f) = \ker(f \circ g)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$f$ and $g$ be nilpotent endomorphism such that : $\ker (f) = \ker(f \circ g)$ in a vector space $V$. ($\dim V $ is finite).

Then, is true that : $\ker(f) = V$ ?

It is hard for me to understand that intuitively...
I've noticed that : $\ker(f) = \ker(f \circ g) \Rightarrow (f(g^n(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0)$

Comment: What is the meaning of $E$ ?

Comment: sorry it is $V$ not $E$, my bad.

Comment: Can you use your observation and the fact that $g$ is nilpotent to show that $f(x) = 0$ for every $x$ in $V$?

Comment: $Ker(f) = Ker(f \circ g) \Rightarrow (f(g(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0) \Rightarrow (f(g^2(x)) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0)$

Comment: @Arthur I might be wrong but I think you only have (and need) $Ker(f \circ g^2) \subseteq Ker(f \circ g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just assume that $\ker(f)=\ker(f\circ g)$, for the moment.

Suppose $x\in\ker (f\circ g^{k+1})$; then $y=g^k(x)\in\ker(f\circ g)=\ker(f)$. This implies that
$$
x\in\ker(f\circ g^k)
$$

Therefore, by induction (fill in the details),
$$
\ker(f\circ g^k)\subseteq\ker(f)
$$

Now apply the assumption that $g$ is nilpotent.